# Angular unit testing component ngIf element is null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I've a component with a few *ngIf statements throughout, most of them like the following

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
<li> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="itemCount && item.GroupId == 4">
        <span class="bridge">{{itemCount}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</li>
... and so on
```

in my spec file I've a test that is trying to check on the scenario whereby the itemCount is not null /empty and the groupId = 4...then checking that the span contains the correct item count.

I've spent hours on variations of this but no matter what I try the attempt to get access to the span results in null and the test fails.

So here's an example of one of the tests

```
if('should show the correct item count', () =>{
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.itemCount = 4;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let bridge = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.bridge'));
    expect(bridge).tobeTruthy();
});
```

As I say above, through many multiples of attempts this is ALWAYS null, no matter what. I've debugged the test and have confirmed that the correct groupId is being used have also confirmed the itemCount is not null or empty so both conditions of the *ngIf should be fulfilled -but the span doesn't exist so I have to presume there's something amiss.

Please excuse typos, I'm copying the code manually but it does run currently, just doesn't succeed.

Any pointers?

**Update**:

Here's more info, the beforeEach where the component is populated with dummy data.

```
const ItemServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('ItemService', ['getItems']);

beforeEach(() =>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ItemComponent],
        providers: [{provide: ItemService, useValue: ItemServiceStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
    itemService = Testbed.inject(ItemService);

    spyOn(itemService, 'getItems').and.callFake(() => of(fakeItems));

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemComponent);
    fixture.autoDetectChanges();
});
```

**Update 2**
Here's the fake data being set

```
describe('item tests', () => {

let fakeItems: Item[];

fakeItems = [
   {GroupId: '2', ItemName: 'test', isExternal: false},
   {GroupId: '3', ItemName: 'testing', isExternal: false},
   {GroupId: '4', ItemName: 'test item', isExternal: false}
];

});
```

Comment: what is the value of `component.items` in the test?

Comment: I'll update the question with that detail...

Comment: @Andrei - I've added more detail but to answer your question the value of component.items in the test corresponds to the fake data I've supplied. I'm debugging and can see the data is there and can see the itemCount is as I've set it (to 4).

Comment: is the fake data - correct objects with any of them having `GroupId == 4`?

Comment: @Andrei yes the item with GroupId == 4 is there, and the item count is being set. I'm getting all this from debugging but perhaps debugging isn't a good place to check this stuff? To be honest unit testing angular is killing me, it's so difficult to get even the most basic thing tested.

Comment: maybe there is a problem in your ts code. could you also provide ts where you set the items data

Comment: @Andrei have updated the question with more detail. The other tests all run and are successful, only this one fails. Also the component I'm testing works perfectly, just this one test fails which makes me believe there's no issue with the ts, just how I'm configuring this one test to 'see' the content of the ngIf span.

Comment: also a component code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
it('should show the correct item count', () =>{
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.items = [...fakeItems];
    component.itemCount = 4;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let bridge = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.bridge'));
    console.log(bridge); // make sure it logs something to the console
    expect(bridge).toBeTruthy();
});
```

If this doesn't work, I am thinking there is an `*ngIf` on top of the `ul` where it is not true and therefore this `ul` is not being displayed.

To test this, try:

```
<ul class="dummy-class" *ngFor="let item of items">
<li> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="itemCount && item.GroupId == 4">
        <span class="bridge">{{itemCount}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</li>
```

```
it('should show the correct item count', () =>{
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.items = [...fakeItems];
    component.itemCount = 4;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let bridge = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ul.dummy-class'));
    console.log(ul); // make sure it logs something to the console
    expect(ul).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.

Comment: So the first suggestion gives me null in the console, the second outputs the UL as expected.

Comment: That is strange, I would imagine the first test working then.

Comment: Actually I was wrong....it worked! Thank you! hours spent on this. God.